# Replacing a SRAM Force hydraulic caliper with a new one

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram, replacement

I'm replacing my SRAM Force hydraulic caliper with a new one, I've drained the old one so there's no fluid in it. When replacing the caliper with a new one how can I put fluid into it? Should I just do a classic bleed or are there special steps to follow for new caliper installation? thanks

Comment: I believe that sharing model of the new one would help, it's not like SRAM manufacturers only one, right? Also, don't they have an installation manual on their website? Or you have some problems understanding it? No shame in the latter, but knowing what exactly you are struggling with would help people give you useful answers.

Comment: I'm changing SRAM Force Caliper with a new SRAM Force Caliper. only the caliper.

Answer (score 5):

This [SRAM video on replacingthe hydraulic hose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXCpHFOLVf0) involves removing all the fluid from the system - the situation you are in now. At the end it says to bleed the brake then links to the standard SRAM bleed process, so presumably that's what you need to do.

The standard bleed process is designed to displace all the old fluid with fresh, so the lower syringe must contain enough fluid to fill the system. I think I'd repeat the steps for removing air bubbles a few more times than SRAM suggests to make sure the system is filled properly and there is no air left in the system. If the lever feels spongy you can of course repeat the bleed process.